# install4j: Whitespaces in vm-parameters via vmoptions (OSX service launcher) generating error

Tags: install4j, exe4j

We are generating a service launcher for our app. In the vmoptions file we do set a parameter which contains whitespaces (e.g. file path):

-Dmy.parameter=my file path

This does not seem to work in the service launcher für OSX (but does for Windows).

Also putting the value in quotes does not work:

-Dmy.file.path="my file path"

Both will generate an error stating "main class not found: file.path"

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the service launchers on Mac OS X that will be fixed in install4j 6.

As a workaround, put the VM parameter with the space in the first line in the .vmoptions file, then it should work.